# How can I list the files in a folder that changed between two branches?

Tags: git, branch

For example, I have this a folder called `myfolder`; how can I list the files in `myfolder` that changed between two branches (`branchA` and `branchB`, say)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading through

```
git help diff
```

The particular command you're looking for is:

```
git diff --name-only $branch1 $branch2 -- $path_to_folder_or_file
```

Answer (score -2):

You can compare the differences between two commits as follows:

```
git log
```

You will get a list off all the commits in your repo:
example..

```
commit 8781017d5d7e507511fd1631b9263620671407ea
Author: DavidANegrete <davidnegrete@g.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed Oct 7 14:18:41 2015 -0600

    complete the method to seach

commit 10eab44a41a4f4141b7cce80ffcaa7a676297bcb
Author: DavidANegrete <davidnegrete@g.harvard.edu>
Date:   Sat Oct 3 18:57:20 2015 -0600
```

Now to compare :

```
get diff 10eab44a41a4f4141b7cce80ffcaa7a676297bcb 8781017d5d7e507511fd1631b9263620671407ea
```

Comment: The OP wants a list of files, not the actual line-by-line difference.